# Extract brand and product category from consumer product manuals

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I have a list of consumer product manuals ( about 100,000 .pdf files ) scrapped from the web .  now i want to categorize the files by manufacturer/brand and a category it belongs .
**For example :**

> Samsung -> Monitors -> [ files list ]
>   Samsung -> Mobile Phones -> [ files list ]
>   etc ...

**What have i done so far :**

- built a list of brands/manufacturers, and a list of categories .
- extracted all the data as text from pdf files using [pyPdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyPdf)
- tokenized the words from a text data with [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

  - it looks like this :

    `...
    ('3Com', 'CD')
    ('Corporation', 'NNP')
    ('reserves', 'NNS')
    ('the', 'DT')
    ('right', 'NN')
    ('to', 'TO')
    ('revise', 'VB')
    ('this', 'DT')
    ('documentation', 'NN')
    ('and', 'CC')
    ('to', 'TO')
    ('make', 'VB')
    ('changes', 'NNS')
    ('in', 'IN')
    ('content', 'NN')
    ('from', 'IN')
    ...`

**The problem i face now:**

How can i match the tokens against my brand/category lists ?
i have never got a chance to work with NLP before , and i am sort of still trying to wrap my brain around this .

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is a NLP issue. Here is how I would do it:

```
brand_names = ['Samsung', 'Lenovo', ...]
category_names = ['Monitors', 'Mobile Phones', ...]

pdf_string = read_my_pdf('theproduct.pdf')
pdf_string_lowered = pdf_string.lower()

brand_names_in_pdf = [brand.lower() in pdf_string_lowered for brand in brand_names] #Everything is lowered to account for case difference
category_names_in_pdf = [category.lower() in pdf_string_lowered for category in category_names]

import itertools
tags = itertools.product(brand_names_in_pdf, category_names_in_pdf)  #Get the tuples of brands and categories
```

This will seem very simple but I think it will work better than any NLP tool you would be using (how would you know if a specific model number is that of a mobile phone, or maybe some words related to mobile phones will be contained in PDF about something else). I think an exhaustive search is more robust.

The only real drawback of this method is related to variations in the words you are looking for. I think a solution to this would be to use regular expressions instead of tokens. For instance, you could accept 'Mobile Phones' or 'Mobile Phone', and categorize them in 'Mobile Phones'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a hybrid approach.  Use a POS tagger to find NNP proper nouns then look them up in a company name dictionary.

This saves you from looking up determiners and other unlikely words.  This *should* increase precision by reducing false positives where someone might use a company name as a verb (xerox, google) for example.  On the downside it might reduce recall by increasing false negatives where a company name gets miss tagged and never looked up in your dictionary.